# How do I column index a keyed table in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have joined two returns series together as:

```
t                            | ar            av     mr            mv   
-----------------------------| ----------------------------------------
2016.01.04D09:51:00.000000000| -0.001061315  513    -0.01507338   576  
2016.01.04D11:37:00.000000000| -0.0004846135 618    -0.001100514  583  
2016.01.04D12:04:00.000000000| -0.0009708739 1619   -0.001653045  1000
```

where this is a table `j` keyed on `t`.

I'm trying to get the correlation of returns, that is `j.ar cor j.mr`.

Currently, the only way I have figured out how to do it is:

```
ar: (0!j) `ar
mr: (0!j) `mr
ar cor mr
```

How should I be doing it? Is it possible to do it without unkeying the table first? (I can't figure out how to extract the columns otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access and operate on the columns directly from the table, they don't have to be pulled out

```
q)j:([t:3?.z.P]ar:3?1f;av:3?1000;mr:3?1f;mv:3?1000)
q)exec ar cor mr from j
0.9999852
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way! Thank you! One question; in this case `select` and `exec` produce identical results; is there a difference in the underlying computation?

Comment: There's always an easier way! That's the beauty of kdb :) There's no difference to the underlying calculation but obviously `exec` returns the float answer while `select` returns the float still embedded in a table